# Почему можно перегружать операторы [],(),->,= только через методы класса?

Tags: c++, ооп

Почему можно перегружать операторы [],(),->,= только через методы класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему - нельзя? Очень даже можно:

```
class Test {
public:
    void operator[](int i) { cout << "[" << i << "]\n"; }
    void operator()(int i) { cout << "(" << i << ")\n"; }
    Test*  operator->()   { cout << "->"; return this; }
    void operator=(int i) { cout << "=" << i << "\n"; }

    int j = 5;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t;
    t[0];
    t(1);
    cout << t->j << endl;
    t=3;
}
```

Более того, насколько я помню, то как раз нельзя эти операторы сделать свободными, а только членами.

А вот это как раз вполне объяснимо - такая перегрузка сделала бы возможным переопределение соответствующих глобальных операторов, что чревато с точки зрения безопасности.

Кроме того, исходя из семантики, для этих операторов *левая* часть *не может не быть* ссылкой на объект класса, поэтому в свободном операторе нет особого смысла - вы все равно должны писать его с первым аргументом - ссылкой на объект класса. А в случае `->` - возвращать указатель... Все эти ограничения и приводят к ограничению на способ реализации.

*"По-моему, так"* (с) Пух

Comment: Защита от перегрузки глобальных операторов опирается на типы, так что я не вижу тут каких-либо проблем с безопасностью. `->` не обязан возвращать указатель, но должен возвращать нечто, с чем может быть использован `->` снова (например, подойдёт любой смарт-поинтер).